# seperate sed command option is not work in my shell file

Tags: bash, sed

my program will delete all comments from the shell file except shebang

```
function removeComment(){
    read -p "$prompt" rmblank
    if [ "$rmblank" = "y" ]
    then
        filecontent=$(echo "$filecontent" | sed -e '/.*\#.*$/d' -e '1i \#!\ \/bin\/bash')
    fi
}
```

the function only works at first sed command that delete all comments but not at second which append shebang in the first line

Comment: Do them in the reverse order.

Comment: This sed command `'/.*\#.*$/d'` will delete all lines which contain `#`. I'm wondering, is this what you need? For example, if a line counts the length of a string `${#foo}` will be deleted.

Comment: `#` can also be part of multi-line strings or heredocs, and just like the shebang, some "comments" can be instructions like `#SBATCH ...`. Accurately removing comments might be impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `i` command is supposed to be followed by a `/` *and a newline* (i.e. the argument must contain a literal newline character). See [the man page](https://ss64.com/osx/sed.html) (and note that the `a` and `c` commands have similar syntax). I'd also recommend avoiding the nonstandard `function` keyword.

```
removeComment(){
    read -p "$prompt" rmblank
    if [ "$rmblank" = "y" ]
    then
        filecontent=$(echo "$filecontent" | sed -e '/.*\#.*$/d' -e '1i \
#!\ \/bin\/bash')
    fi
}
```

But personally, I'd just add the shebang line separately:

```
filecontent=$(echo '#! /bin/bash'; echo "$filecontent" | sed -e '/.*\#.*$/d')
```

(Note that since the first `echo` isn't part of the pipeline, it doesn't go through `sed` and hence doesn't get deleted as a comment.)

BTW, is there a reason for the complex pattern for detecting comments, instead of just `/#/d`? Do you actually want to delete all lines with "#", or just those that *start* with "#"?